Symfony Live components Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
I have a problem and I can't find where the problem comes from after checking my code and the docs. When submitting a form with Live components I do not have a redirection once the data is submitted but a js error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Here is my source:
NewProofCollectionForm.php

#[AsLiveComponent(urlReferenceType: UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL)]
class NewProofCollectionForm extends AbstractController
{
  use DefaultActionTrait;
  use ComponentWithFormTrait;

  protected function instantiateForm(): FormInterface
  {
    return $this->createForm(NewProofCollectionType::class);
  }

  #[LiveAction]
  public function save(
    Request $request,
    TranslatorInterface $translator,
    SlugGeneratorService $slugGenerator,
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
  ): Response {
    // Submit the form! If validation fails, an exception is thrown
    // and the component is automatically re-rendered with the errors
    $this->submitForm();

    $form = $this->getForm();

    /** @var Collections $collection */
    $collection = $this->getForm()->getData();
    /** @var Creators $creator */
    $creator = $this->getUser();
    $collection->setTypeCollection(TypeCollectionEnum::Proof);
    $collection->setSlug($slugGenerator->generateSlug(8));
    $collection->setCreators($creator);

    // Si le créateur à un abonnement gratuit
    if ($creator->isFreeSubscription()) { // Si le créateur à un plan gratuit, on limit la collection à 30 jours
      $dateAutoExpiration = new \DateTimeImmutable('now');
      $collection->setAutoExpiration($dateAutoExpiration->modify('+30 day'));
    }

    // Désactive l'accès publique à la collection
    if ($form->get('desabledCollection')->getData()) {
      $collection->setActive(false);
    }

    if (!$collection->getObjectiveSelection()->getSetSelectionGoal()) {
      $collection->setObjectiveSelection(null);
    }

    // Cryptage du mot de passe de la collection
    if (!empty($collection->getPassword())) {
      $factory = new PasswordHasherFactory(['common' => ['algorithm' => 'bcrypt'],]);
      $passwordHasher = $factory->getPasswordHasher('common');
      $collection->setPassword($passwordHasher->hash($collection->getPassword()));
    }

    $entityManager->persist($collection);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $this->addFlash('success', $translator->trans('Votre colletion à bien été sauvegarder.'));
    $this->resetForm();
 
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_dashboard_creator_collection_show', [
       'slug' => $collection->getSlug(),
    ]);
  }
}


NewProofCollectionForm.html.twig
<div {{ attributes }}>
  <!-- Modal New collection proof -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="newProofModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="newProofModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-lg modal-fullscreen-sm-down">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="newProofModalLabel">{% trans %}Nouvelle collection d'épreuve{% endtrans %}
          </h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{ form_start(form) }}
          {{ form_row(form.name) }}

          {{ component('SelectionGoal', { setSelectionGoal: false, type: '', min: null, max: null, form: form }) }}

          <div class="date-expiration mb-3 mt-3">
            <h4>{% trans %}Date d'expiration{% endtrans %}</h4>
            {{ form_row(form.userExpiration) }}
          </div>
          <div class="collection-password mb-3 mt-3" {{ stimulus_controller('generate-password clipboard
            password-visibility') }} data-generate-password-url-value="{{ url('api_collection_generate_password') }}"
            data-clipboard-success-content-value="<i class='bi bi-clipboard-check-fill'></i>">
            <h4>{% trans %}Définir un mot de passe pour la collection{% endtrans %}</h4>

            <div class="input-group" data-password-visibility-hidden-class="d-none">
              {{ form_widget(form.password) }}
              <button title="{% trans %}Voir le mot de passe{% endtrans %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                type="button" data-action="password-visibility#toggle">
                <span data-password-visibility-target="icon"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i></span>
                <span data-password-visibility-target="icon" class="d-none"><i class="bi bi-eye-slash"></i></span>
              </button>
              <button title="{% trans %}Copier dans le presse-papier{% endtrans %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                type="button" data-action="clipboard#copy" data-clipboard-target="button">
                <i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 d-grid gap-2">
              <button type="button" data-action="click->generate-password#generatePassword" class="btn btn-primary">{%
                trans %}Générer un mot de passe{% endtrans
                %}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="collection-checkbox mb-3 mt-3">
            <h4>{% trans %}Options de la collection{% endtrans %}</h4>
            {{ form_row(form.desabledCollection) }}
            {{ form_row(form.enabledDownload) }}
            {{ component('CollectionWatermarkFormInput') }}
          </div>
          {{ form_row(form._token) }}
          {{ form_end(form, {render_rest: false}) }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i> {% trans %}Fermer{% endtrans %}
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="live#action:prevent" data-live-action-param="save">
            <i class="bi bi-floppy"></i> {% trans %}Sauvegarder la collection{% endtrans %}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

index.html.twig
{{ component('NewProofCollectionForm') }}

I tried to do the redirection like this but I still have the same problem:
$url = $this->generateUrl('app_dashboard_creator_collection_show', ['slug' => $collection->getSlug(),], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);

return $this->redirect($url, 302);

